# Moving multiple Xcode projects with source history to a new GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I am reorganizing my GitHub account to move the projects I completed while following a course into a single repository. I could just copy and move the project folders to the new repository but I would then be deleting all of the commit histories once I delete the old repos.

Is there a way I can push the existing projects to the new repository and maintain their commit history. I get the basics of GitHub but didn't read anything that covered such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with `git subtree`.

```
mkdir [course_name]
cd [course_name]                                                  # create a directory
git init                                                          # initialize a repository
touch .gitkeep
git commit                                                        # create the first commit

# repeat for every one of your project
git subtree add --prefix=[project_name] [project_git_url] master  # add project as subdirectory and preserve history
# end repeat
```

(replace everything in [bracket] to the actual name and directory)